# Select a Large Number of Individual Cells in Excel

Tags: excel

In addition to a single cell, Excel allows you to select multiple unconnected cells independently by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> when clicking the cells.

I use this feature to insert a row between each existing row, which is my ultimate goal. You can do this by independently selecting one cell in each row and then right-clicking and inserting rows.

This process works fine for tens of rows, but in some cases, I need to independently select 1000+ cells in a column to insert a row between each row in a large sheet. To be clear, I'm not talking about ranges. Instead of A1:A1000, I mean to select A1,A2,A3...A1000.

Is this possible without manually clicking each cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a helper column with even numbers this way

- type the value 2 into the first row
- type the value 4 into the second row
- select the two cells and double click the fill handle to fill down to the last row of your data or drag to the desired point.

Below your data, in the same column, enter odd numbers 1,3,5,etc, using a similar technique.

Next, sort your data by the new column.

Viola! Blank rows between all rows of data.